# SilverStripe 3.1.x: How can I show the calendar picker in a DatetimeField?

Tags: date, time, calendar, silverstripe, picker

If I change the DatetimeField to DateField, it works - the calendar picker will show, I have not been able to get it to show in a DatetimeField.  Is there a quick and easy way of doing this?

```
<?php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $db = array(
        "StartDatetime" => "SS_Datetime"
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        //Add a Start Date/time field
        $datetimeField = new DatetimeField("StartDatetime", "Enter a Start Date for the Promotion");
        //Add a calendar picker (only works with DateField but not DatetimeField)
        $datetimeField->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd/MM/yyyy')->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
        $datetimeField->setDescription(sprintf(
            _t('FormField.Example', 'e.g. %s', 'Example format'),
            Convert::raw2xml(Zend_Date::now()->toString($datetimeField->getConfig('dateformat')))
        ));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", $datetimeField);

        return $fields;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to extract the DateField out from the DatetimeField to do this.

eg.

```
$datetimeField->getDateField()->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
```

The same can be done with the TimeField using `getTimeField()`

Comment: what about the time input fields ? is there a way to show the jquery ui time picker ?